# Unknown provider: $ionicPopup

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-popup

I'm implementing Global Error Handling inside an Ionic application. I want to receive an IonicPopup telling me that an error occurred. For the errorExceptionHandler I created a new config based on an existing solution that holds an alert as Global Error Handling.

```
angular
  .module('MyApp', ['ionic'])
  .config(function ($provide, $ionicPopup) {
        $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
            return function (exception, cause) {
                $delegate(exception, cause);
                //Alert works fine
                alert(exception.message);
                //$ionicPopup will follow here
            };
        }]);
    })
```

This immediately resulted into the following error.

> angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to
>   instantiate module app due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown
>   provider: $ionicPopup

What am I missing here?

Comment: try creating factory or service.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you injecting $ionicPopup inside a config function when you have to inject it in a `controller/factory/service`

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/

`config` function accepts `providers`, you can inject only a provider,if at all you need it... you could do something like below.

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function () {
    var injector = angular.injector(['ng']),
        ionicPopup= injector.get('$ionicPopup'),
});
```